Vuforia Cylinder Target pixelated image
I'm having trouble with the Vuforia Cylinder Target in Unity. I set up the target with dimensions of top=0.07, bottom=0.07, and length=0.14. I've double and triple-checked the image ratio calculations (0.63), but no matter what file type I upload (PNG, JPG, RGB, BW, 8-bit, 24-bit in different combos), the texture on the object ends up super pixelated once imported into Unity. And on top of that, the tracking performance is really poor. What's odd is that I'm not even getting a Target Rating (N/A). Anyone have any ideas what might be going wrong here? Am I overlooking something?
Here's the mentioned picture:
Cylinder Target image.
And here's how it looks like in Unity:
Cylinder Target in Unity

you might want to share the image you are using as input and screenshots of you problem to make it clearer

Good point ;) I added the pictures.

For targets like wine bottles the input image should include a white area covering the part of the bottle circumference not covered the label (https://developer.vuforia.com/library/cylinder-targets/recommendations-designing-cylinder-targets). Is your the white/label ratio correct? Does the label look stretched in the target manager?

Thanks for the tip. I was following Vuforia documentation quite precisely. My label image seems to be correctly prepared. What's strange is that although the label seems to be stretched after uploading as a Side Target, in miniature model of the cylinder it looks ok.

Also, please see this old post. The fact that the import in Unity looks pixelated "low-res" is normal https://developer.vuforia.com/forum/creating-ar-trackables/image-target-appears-low-resolution . Regarding tracking quality, have you tried to print on the side something very feature rich like these https://developer.vuforia.com/sites/default/files/sample-apps/targets/imagetargets_targets.pdf . These should really work well, if they do not work then you indeed have an issue with the target creation step.
